# Creating Single Field address locator in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, address, geocoding

I'm trying to create a single field address locator for places with a feature layer that resolves with the name of the polygons which represents buildings in my map, I want to add alternate names for those buildings.

How can I do it?

I've read about the alternate name table but how does this work? Does the JOINID must be the same from the Primary Table in the locator?

Here's the screenshot of the current configuration:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have a map of my university and I want to create an application that tells you the shortest path to the building you want to go:

[image]

The issue here is that I created the single field locator with the features to use geocoding and reverse geocoding. The buildings can have more than one name so that's why I'm trying to figure it out how to add more names to my locator.

If you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to explore the [Alternate Name Table](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/The_alternate_name_table/002500000043000000/) article provided by ESRI. Specifically - look at the Building an Address Locator for Alternate Names.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers! the thing is that I don't live in the US we don't have any zip codes or anything. It would be the same way? or what kind of structure do I have to use?

Comment: I had success in using the Gazeteer geocoder to search for places. You can take a look at it at the [Haldimand County GIS](http://haldimand.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=9dab01cbae224556be207898d3718464) just start typing in the search box "Caledonia" and you will see it populates streets, intersections, and the town. If that example works for what you need I can detail how to build that out. else, I am not too familiar with the alternate table options.

Comment: It's a pretty interesting example. I'm trying to configure that on my android application. Can you show me how to? Does Gazeteer resolves reverse geocode?

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve and what environment you are building in as well as how you are calling ArcGIS into your android app. I'm just trying to understand a bit more

Comment: I've updated my post

Answer (score 2):

See that page to [Creating an address locator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002500000007000000)

I hope help you!